Polar decomposition of $L^2(\mathbb{D},dA)$
While studying Toeplitz operators on the analytic Bergman space $L^2_{a} (\mathbb{D},da)$, I came across what is called in the references a polar decomposition of $L^2(\mathbb{D},dA)$, which claims that given any function $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{D},dA)$ we can write $f$ as
$$f(re^{i\theta})=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{ip\theta}f_{p}(r)$$
where $f_{p}$ is a radial function, I know it's a representation that stems from the orthogonality of $e^{ip_{1}\theta}R$ and $e^{ip_2\theta}R$, where $R$ is the set of functions in $L^{1}([0,1],rdr)$, but I want any references that talk about this decomposition specifically.

For those who are interested, the decomposition method was developed in
the following paper

Zeljko Cucković, N.V. Rao,
Mellin Transform, Monomial Symbols, and Commuting Toeplitz Operators,
Journal of Functional Analysis. https://doi.org/10.1006/jfan.1997.3204

